# PrepareForReuse() to reset UIView width not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reusability

I am stuck at this for a while now, and while I think I know what is the issue I am still not able to solve it. I am working with tableView with each cell having countdown bar animation. Each cell has a custom time duration set by the user. Then a bar animation slides as the time elapses.

I am using `CADisplayLink` to get this animation running, this code is written in controller file and I am just changing the width of a UIView as the time elapses:

```
@objc func handleProgressAnimation() {
    let currenttime = Date()
    let elapsed = currenttime.timeIntervalSince(animationStartDate)
    let totalWidth: Double = 400.0
    print(elapsed)
    let arrayLength = durationBar.count
    var i: Int = 0
    
    
    
    for  _ in 0..<arrayLength {
       let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
       let percentage = (elapsed / Double(durationBar[i].durationTime))
       let newWidth = Double(totalWidth  - (totalWidth * percentage))
        durationBar[i].width = newWidth
        if (percentage < 1)
        {
            if let cell = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell? {
                cell.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(durationBar[indexPath.row].width)
            }
        }
        else {
            if let cell = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell? {
                cell.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = 400
                cell.timeRemainingView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        i = i + 1
    }
 
}
```

When all the bars are decreasing, everything goes fine but as one of the cells time is completed then the UIView width becomes zero and then as the user scrolls that cell is reused and this vanishes the progress bar from other cells where there is still time.

I am using prepareforsegue() method to reset the width of the bar to 400(default value) but that doesn't seem to work.

This is `cellforRow` code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! listTableViewCell
    cell.testlabel.text = "\(duration[indexPath.row].durationTime)"
    cell.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = CGFloat(durationBar[indexPath.row].width)
    
    return cell
    
}
```

And this is `PrepareForReuse()`

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.timeRemainingView.frame.size.width = 400
    self.timeRemainingView.isHidden = false
}
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot. You can see in some cells the time is up, but in others there is still time remaining but the progress bar has disappeared.

Comment: I don't think you can set `width` alone. You have to set the whole `frame` again.

Comment: Got it working! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the frame again. **width** is a *get-only* property.